# How to convert whole directory?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I'm trying to make this code work for a whole directory:

```
import pandas as pd
import pdfkit
import os

df = pd.read_excel("test.xlsx")
df.to_html("file.html")
pdfkit.from_file("file.html", "file2.pdf")
```

However can't seem to make it work..

I've tried the following:

```
directory = r"C:\Users\Max12\Desktop\xml\git\yourubl\attachments\75090058\Status\xlsx"

list = os.listdir(directory)


d = {}
for file in list:
    d[file] = pd.read_excel("test.xlsx")


df.to_html("file.html")
pdfkit.from_file("file.html", "file2.pdf")
```

However unsuccessfully.. Please help!
SO would like a directory of xls, xlsx files to become each their own pdf. So if 10 XLSX, then 10 PDF!

Please help!

Comment: Hi Henry I'm sorry relatively new here. I want a directory of xls, xlsx files to become each their own pdf. So if 10 XLSX, then 10 PDF! Best, Max

Comment: You have to apply your `to_html` or whatever functions you want to convert from HTML to PDF to each one of your files separately, providing a separate path for each one so they don't overwrite. Imagine doing it by hand and code appropriately.

Comment: @ifly6 isn't it possible to index the length of the directory/?

Comment: What did the error message say?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work:

```
import pandas as pd
import os
import pdfkit

config = pdfkit.configuration(
            wkhtmltopdf='C:\\Program Files\\wkhtmltopdf\\bin\\wkhtmltopdf.exe'
         )

directory = r"C:\Users\Max12\Desktop\xml\git\yourubl\attachments\75090058\Status\xlsx"

tmp_file = os.path.join(directory, 'tmp.html')
for file in os.listdir(directory):
    if not (file.endswith('.xlsx') or file.endswith('.xls')):
        continue
    file = os.path.join(directory, file)
    df = pd.read_excel(file)
    df.to_html(tmp_file)
    pdf_file = file[:-(3 if file.endswith('.xls') else 4)] + 'pdf'
    pdfkit.from_file(tmp_file, pdf_file, configuration=config)
if os.path.exists(tmp_file):
    os.remove(tmp_file)
```

If you don't need the explicit `wkhtmltopdf` configuration then you can remove those parts.